# Black dots shown above WooCommerce product thumbnails

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

There are black dots shown above the product thumbnails on my clients WooCommerce website.  They look like they are intended to show multiple images for products but they were not there before updating to the latest version of the content-product.php template file.  The old version was 3.4.0 and the new version is 3.6.0

This picture shows what is happening:

[image: This picture shows what is happening]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the following CSS rule to your child theme `style.css` file

```
ul.products li.product, 
ul.products .wc-block-grid__product, 
.wc-block-grid__products li.product, 
.wc-block-grid__products .wc-block-grid__product {
    list-style: none;
}
```

or if it doesn't work may be this:

```
ul.products li.product, 
ul.products .wc-block-grid__product, 
.wc-block-grid__products li.product, 
.wc-block-grid__products .wc-block-grid__product {
    list-style: none !important;
}
```

Also check that your theme is updated.